# How can I replace single &nbsp;'s with a space but, not if there are multiple &nbsp;s?

Tags: php, html, regex

I assume a regular expression might do the trick but I haven't been able to come up with one that works. I have some fairly long strings in PHP that I need to clean up. In some cases, `&nbsp;` appears in stead of a single space character and in other caes `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` (etc) appears. I'd like to replace all of the single `&nbsp;` occurence with a space but leave the others in place so that the intending can be maintained.

Any thoughts? I presume a regular expression could be used here but I've been struggling with making one for for a while!

Comment: And by what you want to replace a space + a &nbsp;?

Comment: Swishhhhh-HoHe-Swishhhhh-there's anybody here? Are you doing this in your code editor? In this case what is your editor?

Comment: An alternative idea - use `preg_replace_callback('#(&nbsp;)+#')`, have the callback function check if it matched one `&nbsp;` or multiple and return the replacement string accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead to ensure that you don't have other `&nbsp;` around.

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?<!&nbsp;)&nbsp;(?!&nbsp;)~i', ' ', $str);
```

More informations about lookarounds [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: The negative look around worked great, I only need to run this once when importing text so I'm not super worried about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit regular expression that matches `(not-&nbsp;)&nbsp;(not-&nbsp;)` and add the replacement as `$1 $2` (match 1 space match 2).  You may have to code `not-&nbsp;` explicitly as `([^;]|[^p];|[^s]p;|[^b]sp;|[^n]bsp;|[^&]nbsp;)`.

Edit:  While [negative] lookarounds may be useful (and certainly less total code), you may want to measure the speed of each approach.  I have found that certain mechanisms in regular expressions can be painfully slow compared with others, although I cannot speak directly to the speed of lookarounds.  If speed becomes an issue, you can skip the regular expressions and use a combination of `strpos` and `substring` operations and tests which are very often much faster than regular expressions, even if they are more cumbersome to create.  I suggest this only because you have a very explicit string you are looking for; with less definite strings, regex is definitely the way to go.

For this instance (in pseudo-code), your string `strpos` search would be a simple as `strpos($mystring, "&nbsp;")` and once you have found a match, call `strpos($mystring, "&nbsp;&nbsp;")`.  If the two `index` calls return the same value, you can skip this replacement and search the string after the indexed point (start your single `&nbsp;` search after `indexDoubleFound + 12`, but start your double `&nbsp;` search after `indexDoubleFound + 6` to ensure that you don't miss any and you don't unintentionally replace).

Comment: Updated my answer to use the correct function name in PHP (`strpos` instead of `index`).